# How to deal with jsonb objects in postgres databases in cube.js?

Tags: cube.js

I have postgres database with a jsonb column which contains custom attribute keys and values. Is there any approach to get these to show up in the dimensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `->>` json operator for that https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html. For example:

```js
cube(`Users`, {
  sql: `select * from users`,

  // ...

  dimensions: {
    firstName: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.attributes->>'firstName'`,
      type: `string`
    },

    lastName: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.attributes->>'lastName'`,
      type: `string`
    }
  }
})
```